# Get error : Ajax is not defined when install new theme in Magento2

Tags: magento2, theme, conflict

My custom grid in front end using ui_component worked fine before I install new theme. I'm getting this error in console log:

[image]

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, seem that the static content doesn't generate under `pub/static` folder.

1) If your Magento is `developer` mode, you need to delete `pub/static/frontend` and `pub/static/adminhtml`, not delete `.htaccess` folder.

2) And then, refresh your browser. Sometimes, we need to refresh 10 times because the static content needs time to generate automatically.

Now, our static content `pub/static` is symbolic the real file content.

Comment: I have already run the command static-content:deploy. But It's not working. Maybe It come from conflict theme with my custom module.

Comment: No no, don't need to run static content again and again. Follow my instruction. And then clear Browser Cache. Refresh your Browser again and again. Make sure clear Browser Cache also.

Comment: I spot that this error is not show in everypage. Just some page. I have cleand the browser cache. Still get it.

Comment: Try to use Incognito mode.

Comment: Not get better mate. Do something in custom module might remove that js file?

Comment: Update your question with Ajax code.

Comment: My module is using many Ajax code and it worked fine before install new theme.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69473/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-nero-phung).

Comment: @NeroPhung I'm in chat now.